# C# project builds OK , but no binaries produced

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build

Using VS 2012, I build a C# project for a Debug build.  The build succeeds, but the directory `..\bin\debug` is empty.

What can cause that and what can cure it?

Update:  This project builds a DLL

Comment: Are you sure it's building?  Add a syntax error and see if you get a compiler error.  If so, fix it and try again.  If still not output, are you sure it's set to "debug" and not "release"?  Check the property page to see it the "output Path" (under Build tab) has been changed from the Default.

Comment: What kind of project is this? ASP.Net? Winforms? Console? WPF?

Comment: The project builds a DLL

Comment: Set your build diagnostics to the most verbose, and have a look through the build log. There will be something there to tell you what's going on, I reckon.

Answer (score 2):

Check the "Build" tab in the project properties dialog and see what the "Output path" is set to for the "Debug" configuration. It probably builds in a location that's different than the default.

Comment: Thanks Adrian!  first thing I did.  If I open the folder from there, after a build, it is empty

Comment: If that's the case, this sounds like some type of glitch in VS. Try to use the "Clean" option and see if it helps (you can access it with a right click on the project name in "Solution Explorer"). If that doesn't work, I would just try to create a new project and bring over the files from the broken one. Depending on your project, that might be the easier alternative to troubleshooting the "csproj"file.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is that output path for project is wrong.
For checking output path : right click on Project and then click on **Properties**. Then in **Build** Tab check the value of field **output path** . It must be "bin\Debug\" .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for chiming in.  After a double-check I found the error.  The dev had renamed the folder for the project.  I was looking in the old folder!  (face-palm!)